# Jquery Setting Value of html Label at index position in loop

Tags: java, html, ajax, jquery

I have an ajax call and i would like in the success function to loop through every label in a class and set their value to that which has been returned from the server response. Under is the code however this sets all the labels to the same value, this is not what i want i would like to access the index of that item and set only that index to the response value. Where am i going wrong here?:

**JQuery:**

```
 function GetCitizenTypeDescription(citizenTypeId){                 
        $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'getCitizenTypeDescription.htm',
        data:{citizenTypeId:citizenTypeId},
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {       
         $('.citizenTypeDesc').each(function(i){                
                 alert(data);
                 $('.citizenTypeDesc').text(data);      
        });
    }


    });

}


$(document).ready(function() {      


        $(".photos").each(function(i){                  

            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                   var image = new Image();                      
                    image.src =  $(this).val();

                    image.onload = function(){ 

                            var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas")[i].getContext('2d');
                            ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, 320, 240); 
                 }                      
        }     



    });

    $('.citizenTypeDesc').each(function(i){

          var citizenTypeId = document.getElementsByClassName("citizenTypeId")[i].value;
          GetCitizenTypeDescription(citizenTypeId);

    });


});
```

The console returns the correct data i just need to write it to the labels

**Console:**

```
GET http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCitizenTypeDescription.htm?citizenTypeId=2 200 OK 174ms
Response
CRIMINAL

GET http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCitizenTypeDescription.htm?citizenTypeId=3 200 OK 174ms
Response
VICTIM

GET http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCitizenTypeDescription.htm?citizenTypeId=4 200 OK 174ms
Response
....
```

**html**

```
</head>
<body>
<div id ="content">
<c:forEach items="${citizens}" var="citizen">
<div id="table">    
    <div>
        <p><canvas class="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas>
    </div>
        <a href="citizen_registration.htm">Name:- ${citizen.fName}  ${citizen.lName}</a>
        <input type="hidden" id="photo" value="${citizen.photo}" class="photos"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="socialSecurityNumber" value="${citizen.socialSecurityNumber}" />
        <input type="text" class="citizenTypeId" value="${citizen.citizenTypeId}"/>
        <label class="citizenTypeDesc"></label>
</div>
</c:forEach>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does the data string look like when it is returned?

Comment: Presumably `data` represents an array. My guess just glancing at it will you'll need to have something like this instead: 
`$('.citizenTypeDesc').text(data[i]);`

Comment: @JakeZeitz the data is text and it returns only one text item at a time

Comment: as @JakeZeitz said it would be really useful if you could `console.log` data and copy/paste the result

Comment: @Calvin $('.citizenTypeDesc').text(data[i]); returns the last letter in the response text

Comment: question updated with console output

Comment: each time you call the function you are overwriting `.citizenTypeDesc` with the returned data.  Could you give your labels more specific classnames? For example: all dataTypes of `CRIMINAL` will go to `.citizenTypeDesc_1`

Comment: i have to use one label since its a dynamic query that returns the results

Comment: could you add your html so I might grasp your concept a little better?

Comment: @JakeZeitz i updated the question with additional jscript and html included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over all of the `.citizenTypeDesc` labels you could loop over all of the `.citizenTypeId`. Test if each value matches the parameter and then set the label that is within the same parent element.

```
function GetCitizenTypeDescription(citizenTypeId){                 
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'getCitizenTypeDescription.htm',
    data:{citizenTypeId:citizenTypeId},
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {       
       $('.citizenTypeId').each(function(i){                
             //does this value match the parameter
             if($(this).val() === citizenTypeId){ 
                 //find the parent div, in this case .table
                 var parent = $(this).parent();
                 //search for a child with class .citizenTypeDesc
                 var thisCitizenTypeDesc = parent.children('.citizenTypeDesc');

                 thisCitizenTypeDesc.text(data);
             }
       });
    }
  });
}
```